# ¿Cómo traduzco los adjetivos compuestos?

Tags: traducción, significado

Mi tarea inmediata es traducir la frase «she returned to the now-empty village».  Como palabras distintas «now» y «empty» no son problemas, pero creo que la significada cambia cuando se combinan.  ¿Hay algún principio para traducir los adjetivos compuestos en inglés al español?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There's no rule of thumb to make translations, just try to write a sentence in Spanish that creates in the reader the same mental image as the original one creates in the English readers.

Comment: Also, could you give some more examples? There are several ways to modify adjectives in English and you've only mentioned one (time adverb + adjective), is that type of composition specifically what you'd like to translate?

Comment: Como ya se mencionó, no existe una regla para realizar dichas traducciones. En tu caso, yo lo traduciría como la "ciudad abandonada"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una posibilidad para traducir los compuestos del tipo *now-/then-* + adjetivo es hacerlo de la manera más literal:

> She returned to the now-empty village. =
>   *Ella volvió a la aldea ahora vacía.*

O también con una coma:

> *Ella volvió a la aldea, ahora vacía.*

Que equivale a una elipsis de

> *Ella volvió a la aldea, **que estaba** ahora vacía.*

En este tipo de oración puede aparecer una ambigüedad, como aquí: lo que está *ahora vacía* ¿es "ella" o "la aldea"? Pero generalmente el contexto deja bien claro a qué se refiere la frase.

Comment: This is a very good answer. I would have completely overlooked the now-taken-care-of(*) alternative of creating an ellipsis with a comma. ( *= Sorry, I couldn't resist the iterative reference ;) )